# Firewire(iLink) import problem

Tags: adobe-premiere

we use Sony HVR-1000E video camera in video montage and motion graphic class.
We have a problem during a footage import(firewire). OS can't recognize video camera.
Operating system windows 7.
Did someone ever encounter this problem?
Possible conflicts in drivers ? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a problem in video production, but a hardware/compatibility problem, so the question may be better suited over on SuperUser

Comment: Did it ever work? Is there anything interesting in device manager? Say a ! of some sort?